# Ensuring binary compatibility of std::vector with EXE/DLL / Alternative using plain C?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I am creating a shared library which is, for Windows systems, deployed as a DLL.

I am currently wondering how to handle std::vector instantiations that will be dynamically manipulated by my DLL. The DLL should be able to change the content of the vector.

**My Question:** Assuming that there would be no control over which CRT is being used by the client - is this even possible?

If the answer is *yes*, is there a simple way (such as explicitly specifying an allocator)?
From this [Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958) it seems that exporting especially an std::vector would be possible with the given compiler flags for the EXE / DLL... but, as said, I want to assume that the client's compiler settings are unknown.

If the answer is *no*: Would a C interface with plain C pointers be binary compatible (allowing for malloc / free to safely be used by the EXE as well as by the DLL code)?

To give an example, imagine a basic data structure and a function like this in the DLL's header file(s):

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//     API declaration (header from DLL)    //
//////////////////////////////////////////////

struct DataChunk
{
  std::vector<unsigned> someData;
};

MY_EXPORT splitSomeChunks(std::vector<DataContainer> & dataChunks);
```

The client application would use it somehow like this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// calling code (inside client application) //
//////////////////////////////////////////////

std::vector<DataContainer> dataChunks;

//populate dataChunks
//...

//call function splitSomeChunks, which changes the chunks...
//- by splitting some chunks (manipulating the 'someData' member) and
//- by appending the new chunks to the vector
splitSomeChunks(dataChunks);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The only memory management functions that are safe across Windows executable boundaries are the Win32 API ones.  For example, `HeapAlloc`, `GlobalAlloc`, etc.  The calls to `malloc`, `free`, `new[]`, etc. are specific to compilers and compiler options.  I'm speaking specifically if you attempt to allocate in one module, and deallocate / reallocate in another.

Comment: The solution is to produce and distribute a binary for each compiler / compiler version you support instead of compiling with a single compiler version and having to isolate all allocations / not use the standard library across the dll boundry.

Comment: ***allowing for malloc / free to safely be used by the EXE as well as by the DLL code*** No this is not safe either as @PaulMcKenzie said.